# Inserção de chaves estrangeiras pelo Kettle

Tags: chave-estrangeira, pentaho

estou precisando carregar alguns dados que estão em planilhas em um banco relacional, mas venho enfrentando alguns desafios com relação a inserção de chaves estrangeiras.

Nessas imagens vocês conseguem ver que eu insiro primeiramente os dados do projeto, o auto increment do banco gera uma chave, eu a recupero no table input e então ligo esse step com Excel Input da planilha dos dados de relevo.

Eu tenho apenas um projeto e vários relevos relacionados a ele.

Os dados do projeto estão em uma planilha e os dados do relevo estão em uma outra planilha diferente. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao tentar inserir nenhum erro é retornado, porém os dados do relevo não são incluídos. É um problema aparentemente simples, mas estou começando agora a entender o Kettle.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço desde já!

EDIT2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando vários steps de input em sequencia:

Excel input - Table input - Table input - Excel input - Table input

Cada vez que um step de input é utilizado no fluxo, a tabela resultante deste input é resetada, ou seja, no próximo step você só tem o que foi adicionado no ultimo input. O que você precisa é que estes 5 inputs sejam feitos em fluxos separados no mesmo KTR, e unificados por uma chave comum, utilizando os steps de Join (aconselho o Multiway Merge Join, já que há mais de 2 fluxos).

Vejo também que você esta utilizando a opção "Accept filenames from previous step" no seu Excel input. Desta maneira o Excel input irá receber os caminhos absolutos dos arquivos pela tabela que esta chegando no step de input, e não irá utilizar o caminho desejado na lista de arquivos/diretórios.

EDIT:

Caso não seja necessário nenhum outro parâmetro de update, você pode utilizar o step "Execute SQL statements". Neste step você pode efetuar queries com substituição de variáveis, ou seja, linhas de tabela que são alimentadas para este step, irão fazer parte da Query.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Na query que você irá utilizar, você deve colocar um ponto de interrogação nos atributos da query, estes "?" irão ser substituídos na mesma ordem da lista de parametros.

Ex.:
Se uma tabela desta maneira chegar no step:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com uma query desta maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A query sera executada 2 vezes, alterando os "?" na ordem id_projeto, nome e local.

Comment: Na verdade, eu preciso concluir o output da tabela projeto para poder recuperar o id auto increment que será gerado e incluí-lo na tabela relevo. Eu fiz um teste com o merge, como você sugeriu, mas não consigo visualizar como isso seria útil pra mim, já que a conclusão de um fluxo é necessária para o início do outro.

Comment: Eu iria necessitar de um exemplo para poder te ajudar neste caso, não ficou muito claro para mim. Você quer efetuar um update na tabela relevo, a partir de dados da tabela projeto ? Ou a partir de dados da tabela projeto você efetua pesquisas na tabela relevo ?

Comment: Isso, quero efetuar um update na tabela relevo a partir dos dados da tabela projeto. O projeto tem um ID que é gerado automaticamente. O que eu preciso é que esse ID de projeto gerado automaticamente seja inserido na tabela relevo, possibilitando o relacionamento das tabelas. Vou inserir o print na postagem pra ficar claro.

Comment: Como você consegue ver na imagem, eu inseri o projeto e o ID gerado automaticamente foi o 157. Agora, para realizar o relacionamento com a tabela relevo, eu preciso recuperar esse 157 e inserir nesses dados da tabela relevo.

Comment: Eu estava fazendo esse processo manualmente, o problema é que o banco está em constante utilização e como são muitas tabelas, acabou se tornando inviável.

Comment: Editei a resposta com uma possivel solução.

Comment: Deu certo só quando só um valor é recuperado. Por exemplo, quando eu preciso atualizar vários IDs diferentes igual você colocou no seu exemplo, não deu certo. O primeiro número se repetiu para todos, ao invés de cada linha receber um valor diferente. Editei a pergunta com as imagens pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: Pode ser que seja necessário controlar o fluxo de dados com 2 KTR's dentro de um JOB, mas ainda acho que uma clausula WHERE em seu update iria resolver melhor o problema.